# Qt Making a Timer using QLCDNumber

Tags: qt, timer

I am trying to make two timers using QLCDNumber. These timers will be generated as a part of my status bar, in a dll. I have two LCDNumber displays. lcdNumber1 will start at a specified time (e.g. 12:00:00). lcdNumber2 will start at 0 (e.g. 00:00:00).

How am I able to create a timer for lcdNumber2 and let it to start ticking?

How can I add lcdNumber2's timer to lcdNumber1? Or can I create a timer for lcdNumber1 to start ticking from the specified time?

Could anyone please help?

```
QLCDNumber *lcdNumber1 = new QLCDNumber;
lcdNumber1->setNumDigits(8);
lcdNumber1->display(12:00:00);
statusBar->addWidget(lcdNumber1);

QLCDNumber *lcdNumber2 = new QLCDNumber;
lcdNumber2->setNumDigits(8);
lcdNumber2->display(00:00:00);
statusBar->addWidget(lcdNumber2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherit QLCDNumber adding variable time to hold current time and another slot tick()

```
QLCDNumber_my::tick(){
   time++;
   this->display(time);
}
```

and then

```
QLCDNumber_my *lcdNumber1 = new QLCDNumber_my;
lcdNumber1->setNumDigits(8);
lcdNumber1->display(12:00:00);
statusBar->addWidget(lcdNumber1);
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->start(1000);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), lcdNumber1, SLOT(tick()));
```

QLCDNumber is simple displaying widget, it cannot run, to produce time change you need to use sepatare timer (QTimer).

Comment: Thanks for the help. The variable 'time' is an undeclared identifier and 'display' is not a member of StatusBar. Do I have to declare anything in my .cpp or .h file? 

I am implementing this LCDNumber on my status bar, thus I declared to inherit from QStatusBar in my .h. Do I have to inherit from QLCDNumber too?:
`class StatusBar : public QStatusBar`

If I want to click on a QPushButton to activate this timer, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Variable "time" should be declared as private member of your class and be initialized with value in constructor.
In your code you inherit QLCDNumber instead of LCDNumber, no matter, just add new method and new variable time to your inherited class.
To start it from button, please read about [signals and slots](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_Qt).